# При запросе на добавление записи в таблицу mysql все поля пустые, но запись добавляется

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

При запросе на добавление записи в таблицу mysql все поля пустые, но запись добавляется
Файл обработчик:

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
/* проверка соединения */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Groups (groupname, course, housing) VALUES ('$_POST[groupName]', '$_POST[groupCourse]', '$_POST[groupHousing]')";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    echo "OK";

}

/* закрытие соединения */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Ajax отправка данных формы:

```js
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '#addG', function () {
        var gName = $("#groupName").val();
        var gCourse = $("#groupCourse").val();
        var gHousing = $("#groupHousing").val();
        var contentG = $("#gAdd").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : "add.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : contentG,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Сама форма:

```html
<form id="gAdd">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="groupName" id="groupName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="groupCourse" id="groupCourse">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="groupHousing" id="groupHousing">
      </div>
</form>
```

Где косяк, ajax вроде отправляет не пустые поля, а php создает запись с пустыми полями.

Comment: Как бы проверять данные перед добавлением в базу вы не хотите?

Comment: Добавьте в код проверку, что данные не пустые , и они не будут добавляться